# Locked out of Raspberry Pi because of crontab

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I installed a crontab that runs a python script in sudo on my Raspberry Pi upon reboot. Since installing this crontab, I receive this error whenever I try to ssh into my pi:

```
Unable to fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

I think this is because my python script hogs all the RAM on the pi so that it can't start a new ssh session. What can I do to get back into my pi without resetting the SD card?

Comment: Welcome to SO, unfortunately I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a general computing problem; the fact that your own python script causes the condition is irrelevant. Please post over at https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux

Comment: Have you tried directly connecting a screen, keyboard and mouse? There is a chance you could log in that way and adjust the crontab.

Comment: [Cron overrun] You could mount the SD cardon an other machine and remove the crontab file or the job (or temporarily disable cron)

Comment: [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Try logging into the raspberry pi directly using the console.  That may have sufficient memory to log in.

If that fails, then if you have another raspberry pi sd card or linux machine, and a spare sdcard reader,  you can mount your faulty sdcard on the other machine, and edit the crontab files directly to remove the crontab.

Comment: What's the reason for the down vote? This seems like a reasonable answer? It could have been clarified a bit more, saying that you'd might need a monitor and keyboard/mouse for the first option.

Comment: It's an answer to an off-topic question.